How from custom menu item run resource with filter defined?
In  Laravel 10 / nova 4.27 app I added custom menu with products items :
            MenuSection::make('Products', [
                MenuItem::make('Products', '/resources/products'),
                MenuItem::make('Create Product', '/resources/products/new'),
            ])->collapsable(),

Also Product resource has custom filters :
/**
 * Get the filters available for the resource.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function filters(NovaRequest $request)
{
    return [new ProductByStatus];
}

where ProductByStatus defined app/Nova/Filters/ProductByStatus.php:
class ProductByStatus extends Filter
{
    public $name = 'By status';

    public $component = 'select-filter';

    public function apply(NovaRequest $request, $query, $value)
    {
        return $query->where('status', $value);
    }

    public function options(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return ProductStatusEnum::getStatusSelectionItems(labelAsKey: true);
    }

and enum file app/Enums/ProductStatusEnum.php:
enum ProductStatusEnum: string
{
    case DRAFT = 'D';
    case PENDING_REVIEW = 'P';
    case ACTIVE = 'A';
    case INACTIVE = 'I';

    public static function getStatusSelectionItems(bool $labelAsKey = false): array
    {
        $statusSelectionItems = [
            self::DRAFT->value => 'Draft', //  D => Draft
            self::PENDING_REVIEW->value => 'Pending Review',  // P=>Pending Review
            self::ACTIVE->value => 'Active',  // A-Active
            self::INACTIVE->value => 'Inactive',  // I-Inactive
        ];
        $resArray = [];
        foreach ($statusSelectionItems as $key => $label) {
            if($labelAsKey) {
                $resArray[$label] = $key;
            } else {
                $resArray[$key] = $label;
            }
        }

        return $resArray;
    }

Next I want to create a menu item with only Active product, but when I run Product filter with Status = 'Active'
I see such url in my browser :
http://local-nova-products.com/nova/resources/products?products_page=1&products_filter=W3siQXBwXFxOb3ZhXFxGaWx0ZXJzXFxQcm9kdWN0QnlCcmFuZCI6IiJ9LHsiQXBwXFxOb3ZhXFxGaWx0ZXJzXFxQcm9kdWN0QnlTdGF0dXMiOiJEIn0seyJBcHBcXE5vdmFcXEZpbHRlcnNcXFByb2R1Y3RCeVB1Ymxpc2hlZEF0RmlsdGVyIjoiIn1d

How this products_filter created for me to run such filter manually ?
